# Why can't I get annotations in the bibliography here?

Tags: biblatex, biber, latexmk, chicago-style

Funny, I feel like I had it going before. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Book{test1,
  author    = {Bar, Foo},
  title     = {Foo},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
  annote    = {My annotation}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Foo\footcite{test1}
\printbibliography 
\nocite{*} 
\end{document}
```

What I want is the "annote" field at the end of the bibliography entry. No idea why it's not working. You can compile with:

```
latexmk -pdf mwe
```

If you want to.

Comment: There is the `annotation` field, it is however not use by the standard `biblatex` styles ("This field may be useful when implementing a style for annotated bibliographies.
It is not used by all standard bibliography styles.", p. 15 §2.2.2 *Data Fields*). There are `addendum` ("Miscellaneous bibliographic data to be printed at the end of the entry. This is similar to the `note` field except that it is printed at the end of the bibliography entry.", p. 15) and `note`. See the [`biblatex` doicumentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: OK, since you are using `biblatex-chicago`, you will need the `annotation` option: "At the request of Emil Salim, I included in `biblatex-chicago` the ability to produce annotation
annotated bibliographies. If you turn this option on then the contents of your `annotation` (or `annote`) field will be printed after the bibliographical reference. This functionality is currently in a beta state [...]." See p. 58, §4.4.3 *Style Options – Preamble* of [the `biblatex-chicaho` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf).

Comment: The field `annote` seems to be an alias of `annotation`, so you can apply my comment on `annotation` above to `annote`.

Comment: Hi @moewe, all that works is addendum, but thanks! I can't figure out if it's a bug in `biblatex-chicago` or just me doing something wrong, though...

Comment: Did you load `biblatex-chicago` with the `annotation` option like so: `\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false, annotation]{biblatex-chicago}`? That worked on my system rather nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with that or `addendum`... Where in the documentation did you find this stuff?

Also, should we somehow close this question?

Comment: In this case it was just a matter of looking for `annotation` in the documentation. You can delete your own question, if you like; but I suppose, it could also be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I admit that I somehow gave up with the documentation. I think this might happen to someone else, given that it's 145 pages... if you make your answer into an answer (erm) I'll gladly marked it as solved. That way, the next person who has trouble with this stuff might find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `annotation` field is ignored by the standard `biblatex` styles

> This field may be useful when implementing a style for annotated
>   bibliographies. It is not used by all standard bibliography styles.

[`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 15, §2.2.2 *Data Fields*.

You could use the `addendum` or `note` field instead

> `addendum` field (literal): Miscellaneous bibliographic data to be
>   printed at the end of the entry. This is similar to the `note` field
>   except that it is printed at the end of the bibliography entry.

[`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 15, §2.2.2 *Data Fields*.

> `note` field (literal) Miscellaneous bibliographic data which does not
>   fit into any other field. The `note` field may be used to record
>   bibliographic data in a free format. Publication facts such as
>   “Reprint of the edition London 1831” are typical candidates for the
>   note field.

[`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 15, §2.2.2 *Data Fields*.

---

`biblatex-chicago` has the `annotation` option

> At the request of Emil Salim, `biblatex-chicago-notes` has, as of version 0.9, added
>   a package option (see `annotation` below, section 4.4.3) to
>   allow you to produce annotated bibliographies. The formatting of
>   such a bibliography is currently fairly basic, though it conforms
>   with the Manual’s minimal guidelines (14.59). [...]
>   Please consider the `annotation` option a work in progress, but it is
>   usable now. (N.B.: The BibTeX field `annote` serves as an alias for
>   this.)

[`biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf), p. 23, §4.2 *Entry Fields*.

and

> At the request of Emil Salim, I included in `biblatex-chicago` the
>   ability to produce annotated bibliographies. If you turn this option
>   on then the contents of your `annotation` (or `annote`) field will be
>   printed after the bibliographical reference. (You can also use
>   external files to store annotations – please see `biblatex.pdf` §3.11.8
>   for details on how to do this.) This functionality is currently in a
>   beta state, so before you use it please have a look at the
>   documentation for the `annotation` field.

[`biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf), p. 58, §4.4.3 *Style Options – Preamble*.

So in your MWE, all you have to do is to load `biblatex-chicago` with the `annotation` option

```
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false,annotation]{biblatex-chicago}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false,annotation]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{wilde}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]